# How do we define the product of modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reviewing my notes and I noticed that I wrote down the following quotient module: $M/mM$ for $M$ an $R-$module and $m$ an ideal of $R.$ I am assuming $mM$ is the set $mM = \{ax | a \in m, x \in M\}.$ This is clearly a module to me. However, this lead me to wonder whether we can define such a product of modules for arbitrary modules. My guess is no because there may not be a binary function that can define such a product between elements in each module. Or is there?

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong:  $\mathfrak mM$ is not a module (actually, a submodule of $M$). How do you add $am+a'm'$ ($a,a'\in\mathfrak m$, $\;m,m'\in M$?.

$\mathfrak mM$ is really defined as
$$\{\sum_{i=1}^na_i m_i\mid n\in\mathbf N, \;\forall i\;(a_i\in\mathfrak m\wedge m_i\in M) \}, $$
in other words, it is the set of all finite sums of terms of the form $am$.

As to your question, no product of modules is defined in a simple way. The closest structure would be the *tensor product* of two modules over a commutative ring – or the tensor product of a right-module and a left-module over  a possible non-commutative ring

Comment: Oh so are you saying that we can't define $am + a'm'$ as $a''m''$ for some $a'' \in m, m'' \in M$ per my definition? If so, that makes sense.

Also thank you.

Comment: For different $a, a', a''$  you can only write :$am+a'm'=1(\underbrace{am+a'm'}_{m''}$). But in general, $1\not\in\mathfrak m$.

Comment: Right right. That's what I was thinking. Cheers mate. Thanks.

Comment: Wait why do you say that $mM$ is not a module but a submodule. Is a submodule not a module? Do you mean the way I defined it, it's not a module?

Comment: You show it's a module checking it's a submodule, not checking the axioms of modules – unless you have some time to lose… Te way you defined it, no, it's not a subgroup, you have to take all finite sums of such terms.

Comment: @Bernard: What if it was the product of a module with itself?